# How to use a Pre-trained Model with my web api

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I just learned about huggingface and I want to consume few of their pre-trained models with my web api. However, as i am extremely new to this, i have few questions.

I am using below code as a sample (Question Answer Topic)

```
import torch
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForQuestionAnswering

# Load the model and tokenizer
model_name = "deepset/roberta-base-squad2"
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = RobertaForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

# API endpoint function
def answer_question(question, context):
    # Tokenize the question and context
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question, context, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors="pt")
    input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].to(device)
    attention_mask = inputs["attention_mask"].to(device)

    # Perform inference
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

    # Get the predicted start and end positions
    start_logits = outputs.start_logits
    end_logits = outputs.end_logits
    start_index = start_logits.argmax(dim=1).item()
    end_index = end_logits.argmax(dim=1).item()

    # Decode the answer
    answer = tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0][start_index:end_index+1])

    return answer

# Example usage
question = "What is the capital of France?"
context = "Paris is the capital and largest city of France."
answer = answer_question(question, context)
print("Question:", question)
print("Answer:", answer)
```

It works when i execute it as my local python file. However **it takes around 4 seconds** before it gets the answer. If i were to put this code into a Web type application then this much delay is not acceptable, so I would like to know what's the best way to handle it.

Second question is regarding context, what if my context contains **thousands of text files**, which I would need to clean up and provide as context. what are the best ways for handling it?